# Nuxt routing resolves pages instead of api route

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a small problem with Nuxt dynamic routing. I have a serverMiddleware (Express API on /api path with a router) and the following pages folder/structure:

```
/pages
|- /_type
|  |
|  |- /_id.vue
|  |- /index.vue
|
|- /index.vue
```

The main problem is /api/asdf is resolved as /_type/_id.
I don't want to add extra params (like: /type/_type/_id) in the query i want to keep it as short as possible.
Any help/advice is appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works out of the box, but when I modified the router the watcher didn't detected. I had to restart it.